# Using c++ and trying to "nest" some code

Tags: c++, input, namespaces, std, iostream

I'm currently trying to create a basic quiz game in C++.

The following code throws an error when I try to run it, it works if I don't use answer("answer") in the main class and instead substitute it with the actual code.

I wanted to "nest" (I don't know the technical term) some of the code so that I did not have to keep writing it out every time, as you can see i was hoping to write any question followed by answer("answer").

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "QUIZ C++ EDITION!\n";
    cout << "Question 1:\n";
    cout << "What is the colour you get when you mix red and yellow?\n\n";

    question("Orange");

    system("PAUSE");
}

void question(string answer) {
    string input;

    getline(cin, input);

    if (input == answer) {
        cout << "\nCorrectimundo!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nWrongimundo.\n";
    }
    return;
}
```

I have a feeling it's a case of wrong syntax but the IDE is not showing me where the error is unfortunately, it only happens when I run the program.

Comment: What is the error you get while running?

Answer (score 13):

> It looks like you are trying to make a function. Can I help?

– Clippy (1997-2007 RIP) [image]

Two ways to do this. One is to forward declare `question` ahead of its first use.

```
void question(string answer);

int main()
{
    ...
    question("Orange")
    ...
}

void question(string answer)
{ ... }
```

A forward declaration is a promise to the compiler that `question` will be fully defined somewhere else, maybe later in this file, maybe in another file, maybe in a library. But it must be defined somewhere or the program will compile, but it will not link.

And the other is to fully define `question` ahead of it's first use.

```
void question(string answer)
{ ... }

int main()
{
    ...
    question("Orange")
    ...
}
```

I prefer the second approach because there is no possibility of falling into a trap like this:

```
void question(int answer);

int main()
{ 
    ...
    question(42)
    ...
}

void question(string answer)
{ ... }
```

and getting a linker error from changing the forward declaration of `question` and forgetting to change the definition.

Comment: That's a forward _declaration_ though, definitely not a "define"[ition]

Comment: I always get define/declaration terminiology backward. I just looked it up to make sure and I still got it backward. Bad Internet. Bad. Bad. Fixing.

Comment: In Clippy we trust

Comment: Oh Jeeze. You find or make that, @Cheersandhth.-Alf ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a declaration of the function `question` before you can use it in `main`. Add

```
void question(string answer);
```

before the definition of `main`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you must declare a function before you can use it (note, definition is also a declaration), but there is no mention of function `question` before line

```
question("Orange");
```

when it is actually trying to get called. Add a declaration:

```
void question(string answer);

int main()
{
    // the rest of code ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare your function , you can either declare it before main or just write the whole function before main.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add before your main:

void question(string value);